# Unity App Store Connect upload new app version

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, app-store, app-store-connect

I am pretty new to iOS development so I apologize if I will ask something obvious. I have uploaded a Unity game to App Store Connect and successfully published it to the App Store. Over time I have fixed some bugs and I would like to upload a new version. I have created a new version in App Store Connect but I somehow struggle to upload the new build from Xcode. There is a couple questions I have:

- Should Bundle ID stay the same when it is the same app only different versions or should it be different every time?
- When I create a new build from Unity and open it in Xcode I have to set everything up again (AppIcon etc.). It is not a problem but I believe there is a better way. How should I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Should Bundle ID stay the same when it is the same app only different versions or should it be different every time?

Bundle ID should be same if it's a same app in app store

- When I create a new build from Unity and open it in Xcode I have to set everything up again (AppIcon etc.). It is not a problem but I believe there is a better way. How should I do this?

When you build xcode project from Unity, you may use append option to avoid your xcode project being overwritten.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, everything is working now.